# Is there equivelant "-fno-common" compile option for Visual Sutdio for pure C?

Tags: c, hyperlink, compilation, symbols

I'm new to strong & weak symbol concepts. For the following example (**pure C**) code, `x` is defined twice, one strong and one weak. I'd like to make my compiler report error:

`foo.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void f(void);

int x = 15213;

int main(){
    f();
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

`bar.c`

```c
int x;

void f(){
    x = 15212;
}
```

For gcc, "-fno-common" is what I want:

> gcc -o foobar foo.c bar.c -fno-common
>   Thus it reports redefined symbols (x).

**Is there an equivalent compile option in Visual Studio**? (Correct me if I'm wrong described)

Comment: It seems that there is an option equivalent to `-fcommon`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/force-force-file-output?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

This is a link option: not a compile option.  The compiler doesn't know anything about x being declared anywhere else except in the file it is compiling.  The linker, however, sees two x declarations and will generate error 2005 or 1169.

Comment: Yes, it's a link error, instead of a compile error. However, I test in VS2017, the foo.c and bar.c won't cause 2005 or 1169 link error. Only when saving them as ".cpp" files will generate link errors. I'm just interested how to discover and let the linker report error in pure C files.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a solution to this one in C.  The only other option is to force them to C++ compiles by setting the /TP parameter but then it won't pick out C semantic errors.